# Exercise loop "while" - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I am stuck on a task. The exercise is based on the "while" loop.

This is what i need to get as output using a variable that changes the numbers and simply printing "Case" and "Notes".

```
Case 1 : 1 Note
Case 2 : 2 Notes
Case 3 : 4 Notes
Case 4 : 8 Notes
```

Here is my code:

```
function main()
                {
                    var i = 1; 

                    while(i <= 64){
                        document.write("Case " + i + " : " + (i * 1) + " notes" +  "<br>");

                        i = i*2;
                    }


                }

                main();
```

Here is my result:

```
Case 1 : 1 notes
Case 2 : 2 notes
Case 4 : 4 notes
Case 8 : 8 notes
```

As you can see the result is not what i need: i get 1,2,4,8 next to "Case", it should be 1,2,3,4.

Comment: You initialize `i` as `1`, then you double `i` like so `i=i*2`. So the next time through the loop, when you are printing `Case " + i`, what do you expect `i` to equal?

Comment: So many people in a hurry to do your homework for you! :-)

Comment: @ Randy Casburn: thank you I have understand.

Comment: You understand that `i * 1` is the same as `i`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a seperate index counter for the case counting. Something like this:

```js
function main() {
  var i = 1;
  var j = 1;

  while(i <= 64){
    document.write("Case " + j + " : " + i + " notes" +  "<br>");

    i = i*2;
    j++;
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: Now?   `)` extra paren

Comment: @RandyCasburn That was just a copy-paste error from the OP's code. I removed that redundant part from my answer. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Plus one for you. The other solution is good too and I'll plus that one up as well. The nice part is that a single counter was used and the value persevered through the use of `Math.pow()` - but that is the potential downfall of that one too - the method call in a loop is a bit of a smell.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
function main() {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < 4) { 
    document.write('Case ' + (i + 1) + ' : ' + Math.pow(2, i) + ' Notes'); 
    i += 1; 
  }
}
```

Comment: could also do `i++` directly.

Comment: Nice solution, how do you feel about calling the method inside the loop? The other solution is good too. Looks a bit more verbose because of the second variable, but is a bit more efficient. upvote for you.